# Reading a text file with c#

Tags: c#, file-handling

So far this is my code. The problem I am encountering is that the file is not being found.

namespace Assignment_Forms_Aplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Define Variable
        string[] words = new string[10];

        // Read the text from the text file, and insert it into the array
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"Library.txt");
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            words[i] = SR.ReadLine();
        }

        // Close the text file, so other applications/processes can use it
        SR.Close();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Correct your file's path... the exception shows that the file is not found.

Comment: *Another* problem you have is that this is vague and broad because you did not read [ask], did not take the [tour] and need to visit the [help]

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what file is missing. Do you have a file in that directory? By the way. do not link images. Code is made of text and a simple copy/paste action is a lot easier to do and a lot simple for us to understand you code.

Comment: Not to mentions some people may not be able to see the images due to firewall restrictions (i.e, if they're reading from the office or a VPN).

Comment: By default, if you don't specify a directory, the app will look in the current directory.  For an app being run from Visual Studio, this is in the project's `bin` directory.  The error message is showing you the full path it's trying to use.  If this isn't the correct path, you'll have to change `@"Library.txt` to the full path (or a path relative to the VS bin directory, which would work but is a really bad idea).

Comment: Simplified version as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Gailen use the following method:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"location");
```

- If location is correct then this will work
- Assign to variable, for example